# Slug not rendering detail page in Django 2.0

Tags: django, url, django-models, slug, slugify

What is the best way to use slug in this case and make it work properly. I can see the URL on the browser display the items requested but i am unable to render the detailed page. I cant find where the issue is coming from. When i access 'page_detail' the url is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/2019/03/23/greetings/', which is correct based on my input but django throw an error to render the page. Error is:   `TypeError: post_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'`

MODEL:

```
class Post(models.Model):
       STATUS_CHOICES = (
           ('draft', 'Draft'),
           ('published', 'Published'),
       )
       title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
       slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                               unique_for_date='publish')
       author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
       body = models.TextField()
       publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
       created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
       status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                 choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                 default='draft')

       published = PublishedManager()   # Custom Model Manager

       def get_absolute_url(self):
        ''' Canonical URL for post detail.'''
        return reverse('snippets:post-detail',
                        args=[self.publish.year,
                                self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                self.slug])

       class Meta:
           ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

URL

```
app_name = 'snippets'
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('posts/', views.post_list, name='post-list'),
    path('posts/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
]
```

VIEWS

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'snippets/list.html', context)

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, 
                                status='published',
                                publish__year=year,
                                publish__month=month,
                                publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'snippets/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

post_list HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}
   {% block content %}
     <h1>Blog</h1>
     {% for post in posts %}
       <h2>
         <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
           {{ post.title }}
         </a>
       </h2>
       <p class="date">
         Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
       </p>
       {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
```

post_detail HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
   {% block content %}
     <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
     <p class="date">
       Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
     </p>
     {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
   {% endblock %}
```

I am still stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

try to change your views.py to

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, 
                            status='published',
                            publish__year=year,
                            publish__month=month,
                            publish__day=day)
return render(request, 'snippets/detail.html', {'post':post})
```